# Pandas: improve algorithm with find substring in column

Tags: python, string, pandas, indexing, substring

I have dataframe and I try to get only string, where some column contain some strings.

I use:

```
df_res = pd.DataFrame()
for i in substr:
    res = df[df['event_address'].str.contains(i)]
```

`df` looks like:

```
member_id,event_address,event_time,event_duration
g1497o1ofm5a1963,fotki.yandex.ru/users/atanusha/albums,2015-05-01 00:00:05,8
g1497o1ofm5a1963,9829192.ru/apple-iphone.html,2015-05-01 00:00:15,2
g1497o1ofm5a1963,fotki.yandex.ru/users/atanusha/album/165150?&p=3,2015-05-01 00:00:17,2
g1497o1ofm5a1963,fotki.yandex.ru/tags/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC?text=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC&search_author=utpaladev&&p=2,2015-05-01 00:01:31,10
g1497o1ofm5a1963,3gmaster.net,2015-05-01 00:01:41,6
g1497o1ofm5a1963,fotki.yandex.ru/search.xml?text=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC&&p=2,2015-05-01 00:02:01,6
g1497o1ofm5a1963,fotki.yandex.ru/search.xml?text=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC&search_author=Sunny-Fanny&,2015-05-01 00:02:31,2
g1497o1ofm5a1963,fotki.9829192.ru/apple-iphone.html,2015-05-01 00:03:25,6
```

and `substr` is:

```
123.ru/gadgets/communicators
320-8080.ru/mobilephones
3gmaster.net
3-q.ru/products/smartfony/s
9829192.ru/apple-iphone.html
9829192.ru/index.php?cat=1
acer.com/ac/ru/ru/content/group/smartphones
aj.ru
```

I get desirable result with this code, but it's loo long.
I also try to use column(`substr` it's a `substr = urls.url.values.tolist()`)
and I try

```
res = df[df['event_address'].str.contains(urls.url)]
```

but it returns:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Is it any way to make it more faster or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Which type is `substr`? Is that a list of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add `join` by `|` to [str.`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) if need faster solution:

```
res = df[df['event_address'].str.contains('|'.join(urls.url))]
print (res)
          member_id                       event_address           event_time  \
1  g1497o1ofm5a1963        9829192.ru/apple-iphone.html  2015-05-01 00:00:15   
4  g1497o1ofm5a1963                        3gmaster.net  2015-05-01 00:01:41   
7  g1497o1ofm5a1963  fotki.9829192.ru/apple-iphone.html  2015-05-01 00:03:25   

   event_duration  
1               2  
4               6  
7               6
```

Another `list comprehension` solution:

```
res = df[df['event_address'].apply(lambda x: any([n in x for n in urls.url.tolist()]))]
print (res)
          member_id                       event_address           event_time  \
1  g1497o1ofm5a1963        9829192.ru/apple-iphone.html  2015-05-01 00:00:15   
4  g1497o1ofm5a1963                        3gmaster.net  2015-05-01 00:01:41   
7  g1497o1ofm5a1963  fotki.9829192.ru/apple-iphone.html  2015-05-01 00:03:25   

   event_duration  
1               2  
4               6  
7               6
```

**Timings**:

```
#[8000 rows x 4 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [68]: %timeit (df[df['event_address'].str.contains('|'.join(urls.url))])
100 loops, best of 3: 12 ms per loop

In [69]: %timeit (df.ix[df.event_address.map(check_exists)])
10 loops, best of 3: 155 ms per loop

In [70]: %timeit (df.ix[df.event_address.map(lambda x: any([True for i in urls.url.tolist() if i in x]))])
10 loops, best of 3: 163 ms per loop

In [71]: %timeit (df[df['event_address'].apply(lambda x: any([n in x for n in urls.url.tolist()] ))])
10 loops, best of 3: 174 ms per loop
```

Comment: I tried `df['event_address'].str.contains('|'.join(urls.url))` because I need to add `regex=True`, but it return me `sre_constants.error: multiple repeat`

Answer (score 2):

do like this:

```
def check_exists(x):
    for i in substr:
        if i in x:
            return True
    return False

df2 = df.ix[df.event_address.map(check_exists)]
```

or if you like write it in one-line:

```
df.ix[df.event_address.map(lambda x: any([True for i in substr if i in x]))]
```

---